# Need take off nozzle to Reuse drinking water jug

Tags: water

How to remove nozzle from Sparkletts water jug ( the disposable kind that u put in fridge)   so I can reuse and refill it ?

[image: Water jug]

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix for this could be to cut a circle out of the top of the container.
Then you can fill up from the top through the hole you've made without compromising the water seal around the actual nozzle.

You could also place some tape around the hole and around the plastic circle you cut out to take away any sharp edges and also make a crude lid.